# Checking position of a point relative to convex polygon in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry

Just as the title says, I wish to check the position of a point relative to polygon in $\mathbb{R}^2$. My take on this problem is the following:

```
1) draw a horizontal line to the right of each point and extend it to "infinity".
2) cnt =  number of times the line intersects with polygon edges.
3) if(cnt is odd or point is on edge of polygon ) 
      point is inside the polygon 
   else
      point is outside polygon
```

Even though this algorithm works for all types of polygons, it does not use the fact that the polygon is convex. Got any idea how can I optimize it so it makes use of its convexity?

Comment: This is probably one of *the* standard problems in computational geometry. Have you checked out any of the canonical resources?

Comment: I think your algorithm is one of the standard ones. And it works for non-convex *as well as convex* polygon. So, is your question to find an even more efficient algorithm using the fact that polygon is convex?

Comment: @Billiska Yes, I'd like to know if this algorithm can be optimized for convex polygons

Comment: @Billiska It might've passed me earlier, but has you whole answer been deleted?

Comment: Yes, it has. I erred in that without extra modification,  it would still require $O(n)$ time which defeats the purpose.

Comment: @Billiska I take it that you'll add it with that extra modification?